# How to change the domain name's corresponding IP if forget where did he apply for the name

Tags: networking, dns

I forget where did I apply for the domain name 'www.XXX.com'

Now, I want to remap the domain to another IP,

How could I do ?

The domain name's owner is a company.
Thanks

Comment: If you can find the IPS TAG then this will help find who the domain is registered through.

Comment: You might be able to find the domain registration information through a WHOIS query as well. However, many registrars enforce some form of privacy protection. In that case, querying the nameservers for the domain name may also give a hint.

Comment: IPS tags only apply to `.uk` domains.

Answer (score 2):

Use WHOIS to find out the registrar.  You can either use `whois` on the command line if you have a system with that command, or one of the many websites that will do this for you (just search for 'whois lookup').

In the output you'll find the identity of the registrar.  The output for different registries looks very different, but you're looking for a company you don't recognise in the output (or one that rings a bell!).  If all else fails, there'll be a line that looks something like

```
Sponsoring Registrar:Some-Company Inc. (ABC-DEFG)
```

This is the ultimate registrar for the domain, but might not tell you what company you need to contact in order to manage it.  As a last resort, you could try contacting that company who should be able to point you in the right direction.